# size of memory allocated by malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I am assigning a new memory chunk to a pointer, but apparently the size of the chunk is not the one which I pass as a parameter to malloc

```
char *q="tre";
printf("q in main %zu\n", sizeof(q));
q = (char*)malloc(6);
printf("q in main %zu\n", sizeof(q));
```

Outputs

```
8
8
```

The pointer however does  point to a new memory chunk.
How is this possible?

Comment: Do you expect the size of a `char *` to change every time you point it to a different memory address?

Comment: What you get is size of pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` returns size of pointer, in your case it is `(char*)`, it will not give the memory allocated by the `malloc`. Keep the memory size in separate variable for later use.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *q;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(q));
```

`sizeof(q)` refers to the size of the pointer, not the amount of memory it points to.

Comment: Memory is not "allocated to [the pointer]". It's merely allocated, and the pointer points to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are obtaining is the size of the variable `q` as a pointer type. In general all pointers will have the same size in your program.

Since 8 bytes are 64 bits, it seems you are doing 64-bit applications. :)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(q)` returns the size of the pointer `q` which will on a 64 bit machine be 8 bytes, not the size of the memory block allocated at that pointer. `sizeof` is a compile time not a runtime operation.

I'm not clear what you want to do here, but if you want to allocate enough memory for a string at location `s`, then you want to `malloc(strlen(s)+1)` (+1 for the terminating `NULL`).

Perhaps you want to get the size of `malloc()`ed block. There is not a portable way to do this to my knowledge, but `malloc_usable_size` nearly does it on `glibc`. From the man page:

> `malloc_usable_size()` returns the number of bytes available in the dynamically allocated buffer ptr, which may be greater than the requested size (but is guaranteed to be at least as large, if the request was successful). Typically, you should store the requested allocation size rather than use this function.

Note the last sentence.